# What application is taking up my key bindings?

Tags: keyboard, 15.10, shortcut-keys

My keyboard shortcuts (Ctr-Alt-arrow-key) don't work in IntelliJ and I think it's because something is taking up those shortcuts.

One person suggested killing all processes until the keyboard shortcuts work.

How do I find where my keyboard shortcuts are going? Ubuntu 15.10